# NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath returns true and false for the same path in two different classes after a segue (and the file exists)

Tags: ios, swift

I am going crazy with this. I have a class that lists pictures in an album and retrieves a NSURL for each of them, for example

```
"/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0045.JPG"
```

I have put a breakpoint there and checked, file exists all is good.

I store these URLS. On user action I call another class to display one of the images and pass that URL on the segue a an attribute to the new view controller.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "picDetailsSegue" {
        if let picReviewController = segue.destinationViewController as? PicReviewViewController
        {
            if(clickedPicture != nil)
            {
                picReviewController.existingFilePath = clickedPicture.urlPath.path!
                [initialize other stuff...]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But once there,

```
NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(thePath!)
```

just keeps returning false. I have tried many tweaks, like passing the path as a string, using "path" and "relativePath" attributes of the NSURL object, all suggestions I could find online, nothing works, the file is not found and the following always returns nil

```
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: theURL.path!)
```

Console output:

The first time I access the URL and store it:

```
(lldb) print NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(url!.path!)
(Bool) $R1 = true
(lldb) print url!.path
(String?) $R3 = "/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0045.JPG"
```

When I try to access it again

```
(lldb) print NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(clickedPicture.path!.path!)
(Bool) $R4 = false
(lldb) print (clickedPicture.path!.path!)
(String) $R5 = "/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0045.JPG"
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer to Raymond26 and other who might have similar issue, I finally understood that you should never make any assumption on a file path outside your app's sandbox, like "/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0045.JPG"

Instead, you should use the PHAsset API to read and write these files, and if you really need a file path (like I did as I was doing processing with a C library on the file) you should copy the file to your app's temp directory before doing so.

```
static func copyToTemp(asset: PHAsset, desFileName: NSURL, requestedMaxSize: Int) throws
{
    NSLog("copying asset to thumb for editing to: \(desFileName.path) with max size \(requestedMaxSize)")

    // Clean temp as iOS doesnt do much overwriting in general
    if(NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(desFileName.path!))
    {
        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(desFileName)
    }

    if(requestedMaxSize < 0) // No resizing, just copy
    {
        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.synchronous = true
        PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageDataForAsset(asset, options: options, resultHandler: { (data: NSData?, name: String?, orientation: UIImageOrientation, stuff: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) in
            do
            {
                try data?.writeToURL(desFileName, options: NSDataWritingOptions.AtomicWrite)
            }
            catch
            {
                NSLog("error writing full-sized to temp: \(error)")
            }
        })
    }
    else // Copy and resize
    {
        let size = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(requestedMaxSize), CGFloat(requestedMaxSize))
        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.synchronous = true
        options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.HighQualityFormat
        options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeMode.Exact
        PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: size, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.AspectFit, options: options, resultHandler:
        {
            (image: UIImage?, obj: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Void in
            do
            {
                try UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.8)!.writeToURL(desFileName, options: NSDataWritingOptions.AtomicWrite)
            }
            catch
            {
                NSLog("error writing resized to temp: \(error)")
            }

        })
    }
}
```